# How to (un)pivot multiple metrics to a single column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a wide table with various metrics having values either 1 or null. How can I use *pivot* to transform the initial table so that each `transaction_id` is exploded to the number of metrics and all the flags are stored in a single column?

Current table

```
|  transaction_id  |   state |   metric_1   |  metric_2    |    metric_3  |
|  10              |    NY   |      1       |   null       |      1       |
|  20              |    CA   |     null     |     1        |      1       |
```

Expected table

```
|  transaction_id      |  state  |   metric_name   |   flag   |
|  10                  |    NY   |    metric_1     |    1     |
|  10                  |    NY   |    metric_2     |    null  |
|  10                  |    NY   |    metric_3     |    1     |
|  20                  |    CA   |    metric_1     |    null  |  
|  20                  |    CA   |    metric_2     |    1     | 
|  20                  |    CA   |    metric_3     |    1     |
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `CROSS APPLY` is one option.

```
Select A.transaction_id
      ,A.state
      ,B.metric_name
      ,B.flag
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ('metric_1',metric_1)
                     ,('metric_2',metric_2)
                     ,('metric_3',metric_3)
             ) B(metric_name,flag)
```